# Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in. Localhost x Locaweb

Tags: php, localhost

Fiz uma aplicação na minha máquina usando o servidor Wampserver.
Porém ao subir essa aplicação para a Locaweb gera o erro abaixo.
A versão do PHP da Locaweb é 7.1.

> Warning: include_once(/include/head.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/storage/3/46/ab/meusite/public_html/dashboard.php on line 25

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fábio, o servidor não mente, então se ele diz que não existe um arquivo, então provavelmente este arquivo não existe.

O index da sua aplicação provavelmente está localizado na seguinte pasta no servidor da Locaweb:

/home/storage/3/46/ab/meusite/public_html/index.php

Então ao fazer o include desta forma:

```
<?php
include_once('/include/head.php')
?>
```

O servidor irá procurar uma pasta include na raiz do servidor e não na raiz da aplicação:

/include/head.php

Você pode fazer o include o **head.php** utilizando a constante mágica **[__DIR__](http://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/language.constants.predefined.php)** ou a função **[getcwd](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.getcwd.php)**, que vai retornar o diretório básico do arquivo sendo executado, ou ainda com o **DOCUMENT_ROOT** (quando presente), que também aponta para a raiz da aplicação.

+- assim no **index.php**:

```
<?php
include_once(getcwd() . '/include/head.php');

include_once(__DIR__ . '/include/head.php');

include_once($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . 'include/head.php');
?>
```

Uma boa prática, é definir uma constante com o diretório base da sua aplicação e então utilizar sempre que for fazer um include.

**index.php**

```
<?php
define('APP_PATH', getcwd());

include_once(APP_PATH . '/include/head.php');
?>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Dependendo qual o servidor de páginas, tem tb o DOCUMENT_ROOT em $_SERVER, dependendo da intenção do autor (caso ele precise do include em vários diretórios diferentes, coisa que o `__DIR__` e `getcwd()` não resolvem)

Comment: Sim, se utilizar o __DIR__ em um diretório diferente provavelmente não irá funcionar (no index sim). Se o arquivo executado for sempre o index.php, o getcwd() irá funcionar independentemente do diretório. O DOCUMENTE_ROOT realmente é uma alternativa válida.

Comment: Tentei todas a possibilidade que vc me disse e não deu deu certo. Coloquei os includes na raiz do index e funcionou.

Comment: amigo, poste o código com o erro para auxiliar melhor. Já tentou com o DOCUMENT_ROOT?

Comment: Se puder postar a estrutura de pastas, o arquivo que está sendo executado por primeiro (provavelmente o index.php) e em qual arquivo está tento fazer o include, ajuda bastante.